# Using pdfbox, why text can be extracted, but not image

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am using pdfbox to extract image and text from this [pdf](http://sdrv.ms/1193OSR). I have following code for extraction of text:

```
 PDFTextStripper p = new PDFTextStripper();
 String thistext=p.getText(document);
```

Which extracts the text properly. However, when I try to extract images from the same pdf using `ExtractImages` class, the images produced are all pages of the pdf, not the actual images. Is that because of the reason that the pdf might be a scanned copy? If that is true, how come the text is extracted?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the fact that it is scanned is your issue. While I have seen scanned PDFs detect text (and make it highlightable), it is still an image. To test this hypothesis, I would try using a known good PDF such as [this one](http://www.selab.isti.cnr.it/ws-mate/example.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Yes I have tested with other pdfs for which it worked. I was confused about text recognition in scanned documents.